# Make error / Enable monitor mode in Raspberry Pi 3B with Nexmon

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, debian, make

I would like to add monitor mode for my raspberry pi 3B (Not B+) by using Nexmon.
I am trying the part of [Build patches for bcm43430a1 on the RPI3/Zero W or bcm434355c0 on the RPI3+/RPI4 using Raspbian (recommended)]
in this website: https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon
However, I got an error when I did : 
`rooteraspberrypi:/nexmon/patches/bcm43430a1/7_45-41 46/nexmon# make`

ERROR:

COLLECTING STATISTICS read /nexmon/STATISTICS.md for more information
COMPILING src/ioctl.c => obj/ioctl.o(details: log/compiler, log)
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:61: obj/ioct1.o] Error 1

Even though I checked the compiler log, there is no data in it.

Makefile:61

```
$(Q)$(CC)gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ >>.log/compiler.log
```

Your advice will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up installing kali linux which supports nexmon already and that actually did not get this error. (However, even I enabled the owl to receive or send, the function is not working but no error)